# Gecko web browser c# coding

Tags: c#, gecko, geckofx

I just got to know about gecko and used it in my application. I am not able to use previous functions like

```
element.count;
element.Innerhtml;
 document.Readystate;
```

and many other functions.

Are there any alternative functions for gecko browser?
I searched for count method and i found
  `geckoelemnt.Count<>;` 
but that is not wat i wnat as it needs an argument. Any useful links would be helpful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

First you must initialize the browser, then listen to some events. The most important is DocumentComplete (documentReady). There is where it enables you to navigate DOMtree

```
if(!Xpcom.IsInitialized) Xpcom.Initialize("Firefox");
_GeckoWebBrowser _brs = new GeckoWebBrowser() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill };
_brs.Navigate("mypage.html");
_brs.AddMessageEventListener("myFunction", recived);
_brs.DomClick += _brs_DomClick;
_brs.DocumentCompleted += _brs_DocumentCompleted;
```

capture events:

```
void _brs_DocumentCompleted(object sender, Gecko.Events.GeckoDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    var ele = _brs.Document.GetElementsByClassName("myCssClass");
    //All found elements
    foreach (GeckoHtmlElement elem in ele)
    {
        elem.InnerHtml = "My value";
        elem.InsertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",MyDomString);
        //and many other functions

    }

}

void _brs_DomClick(object sender, DomMouseEventArgs e)
{
    //Capture dom click.
}
void recived(string s)
{
    //myfunction from javascript
}
```